EFCore: reference twice to another table gets cycles or multiple cascade paths error
In my database, I want to create a table that references twice another table using a code-first approach. This is the code:
public class ArticleWord
{
    public long ID  { get; set; }
    public Article? Article { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }
    public virtual Word WordTarget { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Word))]
    public long WordId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WordTarget))]
    public long WordTargetId { get; set; }
}

I created the migration successfully, but when I update the database I get this error
Failed executing DbCommand (107ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [ArticleWords] (
    [ID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ArticleID] bigint NULL,
    [WordId] bigint NOT NULL,
    [WordTargetId] bigint NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [ModifiedAt] datetime2 NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ArticleWords] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ArticleWords_Articles_ArticleID] FOREIGN KEY ([ArticleID]) REFERENCES [Articles] ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ArticleWords_Words_WordId] FOREIGN KEY ([WordId]) REFERENCES [Words] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ArticleWords_Words_WordTargetId] FOREIGN KEY ([WordTargetId]) REFERENCES [Words] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 
'FK_ArticleWords_Words_WordTargetId' on table 'ArticleWords' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How can I change the code in order to read the Word twice?
Update
I updated the model but I get the same error
[Table("ArticleWords")]
public class ArticleWord : Table
{
    [JsonPropertyName("article")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public Article? Article { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("word")]
    public Word Word { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("wordTarget")]
    public Word WordTarget { get; set; }
} 

Update/2
I added the WordId to have the option to filter easily by this Id in a lambda expression.

Try taking out the references to Word and WordTarget. If you're using the ForeignKey annotations, they shouldn't be necessary since your WordId and WordTargetId properties already define the relationships since they're decorated.

@Ortund thank you for your comment. I get the same error.

Your update removes the [ForeignKey] data annotations. You need those to map the relationship for both columns. What you'll want to keep is this: `[ForeignKey(nameof(Word))]
public long WordId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(WordTarget))]
public long WordTargetId { get; set; }`


I rolled back the last revision. Questions should remain focused, and not be expanded when answers have been given.

I feel like comments are not allowing proper communication so I'm failing to get the full picture across.
Basically the problem is due to a limitation in SQL Server regarding cascade delete actions.
Each foreign key has its own cascade delete action and SQL Server is trying to ensure that deleting a record won't result in a situation where multiple delete paths exist since it could lead to an unintended cascading effect.
Your original model is build such that if you were to delete a record from the Words table, it could potentially cascade delete records in the ArticleWords table through both foreign key constraints, creating multiple paths for cascade deletes.
The model defines navigation properties for Word and WordTarget both referring to the Word entity as well as establishing the foreign keys for WordId and WordTargetId.
public class ArticleWord
{
    public long ID  { get; set; }
    public Article? Article { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }
    public virtual Word WordTarget { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Word))]
    public long WordId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(WordTarget))]
    public long WordTargetId { get; set; }
}

Your problem is a "one or the other" type of situation where you need to use either the navigation properties OR the [ForeignKey] decorated properties. When you do that, the cascade delete issue goes away.
So either of the following models should work:
// Using navigation properties.
public class ArticleWord
{
    public long ID  { get; set; }
    public Article? Article { get; set; }
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }
    public virtual Word WordTarget { get; set; }
}

OR
// Using [ForeignKey]
public class ArticleWord
{
    public long ID  { get; set; }
    public Article? Article { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Word")]
    public long WordId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Word")]
    public long WordTargetId { get; set; }
}


Thank you for your comment. In the last code, how can you define [ForeignKey(nameof(WordTarget))]? WordTarget is not a class, it should be [ForeignKey(nameof(Word))]

I tried to use the example with public virtual Word Word { get; set; } but I get the same error.

I've updated the answer to show how to define [ForeignKey] annotations correctly. That should sort you out

Tnx. I'm confused. [ForeignKey("Word")] is OK because I have a model with this name. but [ForeignKey("WordTarget")] where is it pointing at?

My mistake; both should be [ForeignKey("Word")] since the value refers to the table name being referenced by the foreign key

Thank you so much, I have one last question. I updated the main post. How can I get the Word object for both WordId and WordTargetId?

Since the Id columns store the PK value of the associated Words record, you'll have to query them separately by looping through the set of articles and querying them individually for each Article
